# Divisors, Sections, Vanishing

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $D=\sum_{i=0}^n\left.n_iD_i\right.$ be a Weil divisor on a nonsingular, projective variety $X$. Then, it corresponds to a Cartier divisor $D$, which corresponds to a line bundle $\mathcal{L}:=\mathcal{L}(D)$ and there exists a section $s\in\mathcal{L}(X)$ such that $D$ is the divisor of zeros of $s$. Now, I am wondering: What is the vanishing set of $s$? It feels like it should be

$\displaystyle Z(s)=\bigcup_{\substack{0\le i\le n\\n_i \ge 0}} D_i$

Is this true and if yes, can you provide a proof? It feels like this should be well-known, but I cannot find any good references. If you could provide any, that would also be nice.

Comment: What distinction do you make between "the divisor of zeros of the section $s$" of which you write that it is $D$ and "the vanishing set of $s$" of which you conjecture that it is $Z(s)$, the positive part of $D$?

Comment: This comment made me realize my mistake and my confusion xD. There is really nothing more to say. I will accept your answer and remove my comment, it would just be confusing to anyone else.

Comment: All right. However your deleted comment made me realize that my answer wasn't optimal and I have just edited it. So thanks for your constructive criticism!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the *Cartier* divisor $D=\Sigma p_kD_k-\Sigma n_lE_l$ ( with $p_k, n_l>0$ ) and a covering $(U_i)$ of $X$ such that on each $U_i$ the Cartier divisor $D\cap U_i$ is given by a rational function $f_i\in \mathcal {Rat}(U_i)$. The line bundle $\mathcal L=\mathcal O(D)$ may be defined  by the  Cech cocycle $g_{ij}=f_i/f_j \in \mathcal O^\ast(U_i\cap U_j)$.
A better, more concrete, description of $\mathcal L =\mathcal O(D)$ is that as a sheaf it is the sub-$\mathcal O_X$-Module $\mathcal L\subset \mathcal {Rat}_X$ which restricted to $U_i$  equals $\mathcal L |U_i=\frac{1}{f_i} \mathcal O_{U_i}$.

The line bundle $\mathcal L$ then has a canonical *rational* section $s=1 \in \Gamma(X, \mathcal L)\subset \mathcal Rat(X)$. We have  trivializations of $\mathcal L$ attached to our data, namely $\mathcal L|U_i \stackrel {\simeq}{\longrightarrow} \mathcal O_{U_i}:g\mapsto gf_i$, mapping $s|u_i=1\in \Gamma(U_i, \mathcal L)$ to $f_i\in \Gamma (U_i,\mathcal {Rat}(U_i))$ 
And now it is completely tautological that the divisor of $s$ is  $D$, since that divisor is given by the $f_i$'s on $U_i$.

**Remarks**
1) As you see, the fact that $X$ is projective is actually irrelevant.
2) The construction works on any scheme, however singular it may be, *as long as you consider Cartier divisors*.
3) If your scheme is separated, noetherian, integral and locally factorial, you can indeed associate to each Weil divisor a unique Cartier divisor and then apply the preceding considerations. But this is rather a different issue: your question is really about cartier divisors.

Comment: I have just edited my answer, taking into account  your (now deleted) comment which made me realize that I should have expressed myself more clearly.

Comment: I feel that you need to take $D$ to be an effective divisor for this global section to exist. If such a section $s$ existed then $s|U_i=1\rightarrow f_i\in\Gamma(U_i,Rat(U_i))$ but this map should be a trivialization of $\mathcal L$ so the image should lie in $\Gamma(U_i,O_{U_i}).$ This implies that $D$ is effective.

Comment: @Lalit Jain. No, not at all, you don't need $D$ to be effective. If you read my answer carefully, you will notice that I wrote  (in *italics* even!) that the function $s=1$ gives a **RATIONAL** section of $\Gamma (X,\mathcal L)$. What might seem a bit strange is that this section $s=1$ seen as a global section of $\mathcal L$ does have poles  along the prime divisors $E_l$ of $D$ endowed with a negative coeeficient $n_l$.